# Importing SASS mixin into SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I have a file called **mixins.sass** with following code:

```
=loader
  .loader
    margin: 100px auto
    font-size: 25px
    width: 1em
    height: 1em
    border-radius: 50%
    position: relative
    text-indent: -9999em
    -webkit-animation: load5 1.1s infinite ease
    animation: load5 1.1s infinite ease
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0)
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0)
    transform: translateZ(0)
```

I'm trying to import it into a SCSS file, like:

```
#loader_div {
  +loader
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
```

But, I get error:

> Invalid CSS after "...ition: absolute": expected "{", was ";"

**How can I import SASS mixin into SCSS?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got my answer, the difference lies in way of defining and importing SASS/SCSS mixin.

**SCSS**

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
  .
  .
  .
}

.box { @include border-radius(10px); }
```

**SASS**

```
=border-radius($radius)
  .
  .
  .

.box
  +border-radius(10px)
```

So, for my case when I did `@include loader;`, it fixed my issue.

**Hope This Helps Someone**